# Operador ternário " ?: "

Tags: php, php-7, php-5

Recentemente entrei em uma discução com os colegas de trabalho sobre a funcionalidade mais compacta do if ternário ( x ?: 10) e alguns deles disseram que o mesmo seria retirado no php 7. Fiz uma busca na web e não achei nada relacionado a isso.

Existe alguma informação sobre isso?

Comment: Nem sei o que fazer com esta pergunta. Fechei agora como não claro por faltar uma informação que indique sobre isso. Se for só rumor acéfalo acho que é fora de de escopo, se for algo pra levar a sério talvez dê para responder ou talvez seja baseada em opinião, ou até duplicata já que o assunto, no geral, já foi abordado algumas vezes.

Comment: Eu acho que ele só quis saber se o operador foi retirado no PHP7 (não foi), porque parece que os colegas se confundiram com a introdução do `Null Coalescing`.

Comment: No mínimo baseada em opiniões. Não há registros da remoção do operador em qualquer parte da documentação, mesmo ela estando atualizada para versão 7. Tanto que a informação sobre esse operador está ao lado do `null coallesce`, que devem ter se confundido.

Comment: Até hoje não removeram a palavra chave `var` ou o comportamento do construtor com o mesmo nome da classe. Leva algumas eras para o pessoal do desenvolvimento retirar qualquer coisa na linguagem.

Comment: Então, durante a discussão um deles falou que disseram essa informação em uma palestra sobre PHP. Eu fiz uma pesquisa e não achei nada dizendo que essa funcionalidade seria tirada no PHP 7. E também achei estranho por causa da insersão da null Coalescing, que é uma melhoria do elvis operator. Resolvi perguntar para saber se mais alguém tinha essa informação da retirada da funcionalidade.

Comment: As pessoas adoram inventar boatos baseado em pedaços de informações, lembro da época que falavam que require era lento e include rápido. PHP é uma zona de boatos por parte dos desenvolvedores infelizmente :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O nome desse operador é [elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator).

Ele ainda existe no PHP 7. Pode ser só questão de compatibilidade ou até visando por conforto para quem já é acostumado, mas só quem desenvolve a linguagem pode responder com certeza.

No PHP 7 existe [null coalescing operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) (`??`) e este operador <strike>faz a mesma coisa</strike><sup>ver edição</sup>.

A principal diferença entre eles é que o *null coalesce* não vai gerar um `E_NOTICE` quando a variável não for definida.

```
$a = null;

print $a ?? 'não há valor';  // Saída: não há valor
print $a ?: 'não há valor';  // Saída: não há valor

print $b ?? 'não há valor';  // Saída: não há valor
print $b ?: 'não há valor';  // Notice: Undefined variable: b
```

---

#### Edit:

Eles não fazem exatamente a mesma coisa, há uma diferença importante ainda não mencionada. O operador [null coalescing](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) (`??`) avalia sua segunda expressão apenas se a primeira expressão for `null` ou não atribuída ainda. Ex.:

```
null ?? 'Teste'  == 'Teste';
```

Já o [operador Elvis](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) avalia a segunda expressão apenas se a primeira expressão for *falsy*, ou seja, um valor que, se [convertido para `boolean`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), tem o valor `false`. [Veja esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/271721/6333) com uma explicação mais detalhada. Ex.:

```
0 ?: 'Teste'  == 'Teste';
```

Alguns exemplos que demonstram a diferença entre os operadores:

```
null ?: 'Nope' == Nope
null ?? 'Nope' == Nope

'' ?: 'Nope' == Nope
'' ?? 'Nope' == ''

' ' ?: 'Nope' == ' '
' ' ?? 'Nope' == ' '

false ?: 'Nope' == Nope
false ?? 'Nope' == false

0 ?: 'Nope' == Nope
0 ?? 'Nope' == 0

1 ?: 'Nope' == 1
1 ?? 'Nope' == 1

[] ?: 'Nope' == Nope
[] ?? 'Nope' == []
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/Operadores-Ternario-vs-Null-Coalesce) com o código funcionando.</sup>

Comment: É exatamente isso.
Acredito que meu colega estava errado sobre a retirada da funcionalidade. Fiquei com a pulga atrás da orelha porque o mesmo disse que ouviu essa informção em uma palestra sobre php há pouco tempo.