# Qual é a função do operador «??» (duas interrogações) em PHP?

Tags: php, operadores, php-7

Analisando um *script* PHP em certo trecho me deparei com essa linha

```
$valor = $_GET['id'] ?? 1;
```

Qual a interpretação desse código? O que ele faz?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O `??` é conhecido como *null coalescing* foi adicionado no [PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php). Sua funcionalidade é retornar o primeiro operando se ele existir e não for nulo do contrário retorna o segundo.

O código em PHP 7

```
$valor = $_GET['id'] ?? 1;
```

Pode ser traduzido em PHP 5 como

```
 $valor = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 1;
```

**Relacionadas:**

[O que signfica o operador “?:” no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80904/91)

[Operador ternário “ ?: ”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/226649/91)

**O que não fazer**: [É possível utilizar o operador ternário em várias condições simultaneamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/230908/91)

Comment: e este? $valor = $_GET['id']  ?? $_POST['id'] ?? 1;

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo tenta pegar o valor de uma chave chamada `id` primeiro em `$_GET` se não existir tenta em `$_POST` caso não encontre no último define como valor padrão o `1`

Comment: show de bola :)

Answer (score 6):

[O mesmo que em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44133/101) e outras linguagens, é o [*null-coalescing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator#PHP), mas como nulo é um conceito confuso em PHP, a verificação é se a variável existe. É o mesmo que escrever:

```
$valor = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 1;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Operator/NullCoalescing.php).

Comment: valeu o retorno, mas não tenho a minima noção em C#

Comment: Documentação do PHP [aqui](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Comment: No PHP, pelo menos, o *elvis operator* é o `?:` e tem um comportamento diferente do *null coalescing*.

Comment: Nem precisa ter, por isso tudo o que precisava saber está na resposta.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss mudei lá, novamente PHP sendo PHP.