# O que são os valores truthy e falsy?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Qual a diferença de `true` e `false` para *truthy* e *falsy* no JavaScript? São apenas valores `true` e `false` de "terceiros", por exemplo de uma variável?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O JavaScript possui um mecanismo de coerção de tipos: quando um valor de determinado tipo é utilizado em um contexto que espera um tipo diferente, ocorre uma conversão implícita para o tipo esperado.

É o caso do segundo exemplo da resposta do Francisco: em `if(1) {...`, o `if` espera um valor booleano, `true` ou `false`. Como recebeu `1`, ele vai "dar um jeito" de interpretar esse valor numérico como booleano. Coloquei aspas no "dar um jeito" porque na verdade não é de improviso, na especificação da linguagem existem [regras claras](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-type-conversion) para as conversões entre tipos. As regras às vezes podem não ser intuitivas, mas são claramente definidas.

Assim, valores *truthy* são aqueles que resultam em `true` quando convertidos para o tipo booleano, e os *falsy* (ou *falsey*) são os que resultam em `false` quando submetidos a essa conversão.

Conforme [tabela de conversão para Boolean](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-toboolean) presente na especificação da linguagem:

- **São *truthy*** os valores dos tipos Object, Symbol (introduzido no ES6), strings não vazias e números diferentes de `±0`.
- **São *falsey*** os valores `null`, `undefined`, `±0`, `NaN` e strings vazias.

Isso vale para todos os contextos que esperam valores booleanos, incluindo expressões esperadas por `if`, `while`, `for` (no segundo argumento) e pelo operador `!`.

Um ponto que costuma confundir as pessoas é que dois valores *truthy* ou *falsey* não são necessariamente equivalentes em outros contextos. Por exemplo, em comparações com `==` [as regras de conversão são outras](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), pois o objetivo da conversão no contexto de comparação de igualdade é igualar os tipos nos dois lados do operador, e não converter para booleano. Por isso é comum surgirem [dúvidas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13799497/825789) sobre casos [aparentemente bizarros](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat), como isto:

```
if(1)   // entra no if, logo é truthy
if({})  // também entra no if, também é truthy
1 == {} // false!
```

Answer (score 11):

Em javascript nós possuímos as variáveis de tipo booleano de forma nativa, que podem conter `true` ou `false`. Veja um exemplo:

```
if (true) //Dará "true"
```

O valor `true` tem um tipo booleano, ou seja, retornará true.

Mas muitas vezes nós queremos utilizar uma condição booleana em valores não booleanos, e essas expressões são chamadas de `truthy` e `falsey`. Veja um exemplo:

```
if (1) //Dará truthy
```

O valor `1` tem um tipo inteiro diferente de `0`, ou seja, retornará truthy.

Esse tipo de coisa é bem util para checar se um valor é `0` ou `nulo`.

*Veja mais sobre isso na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Boolean).*