# Erro ao tentar acessar uma propriedade de um objeto em um componente React

Tags: javascript, react

estou com um problema para acessar informações de um array que tem um objeto dentro, usando React.

Essa é a função que trás meu json e altera o estado da aplicação, ele cria um times.nome, times.players e times.foto, no caso isso vai virar um array de objetos

```
getTimes () {
    ajax().get(`./src/json/times.json`)
  .then(result => {
            this.setState({
                times: result.map((time) => ({
                    nome: time.time,
                    players: time.player,
                    fotos: time.foto
                }))
            })
        })
}
```

Aqui eu passo ele para meu app-content

```
render() {
    return <AppContent 
        times={this.state.times}
    />
}
```

Nele, eu renderizo meu componente

```
<TimeCasa times= {times} />
```

Até aqui tudo certo, porém lá no meu componente

```
const TimeCasa = ({times}) => {

let pos = times[0]
console.log(pos)
return (
<div className='wrapper-casa'>
    <h1 className="time">{pos.nome}</h1>
```

o times[0] encontra o objeto normalmente e eu atribui ele a variavel pos, dentro dessa variavel eu chamei o pos.nome e ele da erro dizendo que não é possivel acessar nome de undefined, sendo que pos não é undefined, ele é um objeto que contem a key nome. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Qual o retorno do `console.log(pos)`?

Comment: Aqui ta funcionando suave: https://codesandbox.io/s/p7yvo599qm

Comment: O retorno do console.log(pos) é: {nome: "Time A", players: Array(5), fotos: Array(5)}

Então cara, olhei seu sandbox, meu código em teoria ta igual, muito estranho isso

Comment: Cara, faz o seguinte, mete um `{pos && pos.nome}` dentro do h1, vê se vai

Comment: Funcionou!! vc sabe me explicar o porque?

Só pra te explicar uma coisa, se eu tentasse colocar apenas {pos} dentro do H1, ele dava erro pq eu tava tentando colocar um objeto como child, até ai blz, é pra dar erro mesmo, mas se eu não fechasse a pagina, voltasse no codigo e colocasse pos.nome e deixasse o hot reload atualizar, funcionava, quando eu dava F5 parava de novo... fazendo do seu jeito deu certo!

Comment: O render do TimeCasa estava sendo chamando antes que o ajax terminasse, deve-se tomar este tipo de cuidado.

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, como eu poderia fazer pra segurar o render até o ajax terminar? e só pra aprender porque com {pos && pos.nome} ele espera o ajax terminar? não entendi a diferença

Comment: Escrevi uma resposta mais completa, caso eu tenha ajudado a solucionar seu problema, por favor marque-a como correta. =)

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o mostrado na pergunta, o código parece funcionar normalmente quando [testado em um sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/p7yvo599qm).

Isso pode estar ocorrendo por problemas de timing, onde o render do component `TimeCasa` está sendo chamando antes do estado `times` ser preenchido.

Isso é um problema bastante comum quando se trata com métodos assíncronos ou que não possuem uma resposta imediata.

Uma boa forma de consertar isso é utilizando do [Short Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), ou [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Você poderia simplesmente checar se o valor de `pos`(considerando que ele tem uma referência do primeiro valor do array `times`) é um valor `truthy`:

```
<h1 className="time">{pos && pos.nome}</h1>
```

Se não entendeu muito bem, recomendo ler [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271693/valores-truthy-e-falsy) e o link que deixei acima sobre conditional rendering.

#### Como eu poderia fazer pra segurar o render até o ajax terminar?

Antes que o render seja chamado, o método `componentWillMount` é chamado, você pode fazer as operações la dentro, mas mesmo assim não é certo que elas serão terminadas antes que o render seja chamado, inclusive não é muito recomendado que o use, veja [aqui](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html) o porque.

Uma forma que garantiria seria retornar nada no render caso o valor de `times` ainda não esteja preenchido, mas eu também não recomendo que faça isso, talvez mostrar um loading seja melhor.