# Dificuldades no operador logico OR

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com dificuldades de montar o operador logico OR `||` usando javascript.

Antes do envio deve verificar se o `input file` foi selecionado ou se `input url` foi digitado.

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
  if (($('input[type=file]').val() == "") || ($('#url').val() == "")) {
    alert('O campo Arquivo e ou URL deve ser prenchidos.');
    return false;
  }
});
```

> ERRO: Ta exigindo os dois campos.
>
> Desejo: Que um dos dois campos estejam com valor.

Comment: Qual o problema que está tendo? Eu fiz os testes aqui com o seu código e está funcionando normal.

Comment: @VictorCarnaval Ta exigindo os dois campos.

Comment: Sim, você está usando o operador lógico `||` (OU / *OR* ), ou seja, quando um dos casos for igual a `true` o `if` será executado. Caso queira executar o `if` somente quando os dois campos estiverem vazios, troque o operador `||` por `&&` (E / *AND* ).

Comment: @Tiago Está exigindo os dois campos, assim como esperado pelo `if` que você postou. O `||` implica que se uma das condições for verdadeira, já satisfaz o `if`.

Comment: @VictorCarnaval Essa é a minha intenção. Que seja preenchido ou o input file ou url ou os dois.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Você está usando o operador errado.

---

A sua condição prevê que se o campo da URL estiver vazio **ou** se o campo da URL estiver vazio o código será executado. Isso significa que:

- Se o campo do arquivo estiver vazio, o alerta será mostrado (mesmo que a URL estiver válido);
- Se o campo da URL estiver vazio, o alerta será mostrado (mesmo que o arquivo estiver válido);
- Se ambos os campos estiverem vazios.

O que você quer é verificar se **os dois campos** estão vazios. Neste caso, o que você precisa é do operador lógico ***and*** (`&&`):

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const $nameField = $('[name="name"]');
  const $ageField = $('[name="age"]');
  
  if ($nameField.val() === '' && $nameField.val() === '') {
    alert('Inválido!');
    return;
  }
  
  alert('Válido!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nome" />
  <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Idade" />
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

PS: Em relação ao `if`, não é necessário fazer a comparação de vazio em uma string vazia. Logo, você pode trocar:

```
$nameVal.val() === ''
```

Por:

```
!$nameVal.val()
```

Ficando:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const $nameField = $('[name="name"]');
  const $ageField = $('[name="age"]');
  
  if (!$nameField.val() && !$nameField.val()) {
    alert('Inválido!');
    return;
  }
  
  alert('Válido!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nome" />
  <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Idade" />
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Isso acontece tendo em vista que strings vazias (`''`) são considerados [valores *falsey*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/271721/69296) no JavaScript.