# IndexError: list index out of range ao verificar parênteses balanceados

Tags: python

Alguém sabe por que está devolvendo *"list index out of range"*?

```
def balanceada(string):
    pilha = []
    for i in string:
        if i != '(' or i != '[' or i != '{' or i != '<' or i != ')' or i != ']' or i != '}' or i != '>':
            pass
        if i == '(' or i == '[' or i == '{' or i == "<":
            pilha.append(i)
        else:
            if (i == ")" and pilha[-1] == "(") or (i == "]" and pilha[-1] == "[") or (i == "}" and pilha[-1] == "{") or (i == ">" and pilha[-1] == "<"):
                pilha.pop()
            else:
                return False
    if len(pilha) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 3):

<sup>*Geralmente para problemas no código, é interessante você colocar os casos de teste que deram erro (quais strings você usou para testar), assim os demais não precisam "adivinhar" e podem dar respostas mais precisas. Tudo bem que neste caso não foi tão complicado achar o problema, mas fica a dica para as próximas.*</sup>

---

A lógica da sua função `balanceada` é adicionar um elemento na lista `pilha` quando ele é um caractere de abertura (`(`, `[`, `{` ou `<`), e removê-lo quando o fechamento correspondente é encontrado.

Isso quer dizer que em muitos casos, no meio da execução, a pilha pode estar vazia. Por exemplo, se você passar a string `'())'`:

- o primeiro `(` é adicionado na lista
- o primeiro `)` é encontrado, o `(` é removido da lista (então agora a lista está vazia)
- o segundo `)` é encontrado, você tenta acessar `pilha[-1]`. Mas como a lista está vazia, qualquer tentativa de acessar qualquer elemento dá erro

No caso, `pilha[-1]` [acessa o elemento na última posição da lista](https://stackoverflow.com/a/930398). Mas como a lista está vazia, não existe o último elemento (na verdade, como ela está vazia, não existe nenhum), por isso ocorre o [`IndexError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError).

---

Tem várias coisas que podem melhorar no código (não apenas a verificação se a lista está vazia). Em vez de fazer `if i != '(' or i != '[' ...`, você poderia colocar os elementos válidos em uma lista e testar se o caractere está nesta lista, [usando `in`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7571665):

```
def  balanceada(string):
    abertura = [ '(', '[', '{', '<' ]
    fechamento = [ ')', ']', '}', '>' ]
    correspondentes = { fecha: abre for abre, fecha in zip(abertura, fechamento) }
    pilha = []
    for i in string:
        if i in abertura: # se é (, {, [ ou <
            pilha.append(i)
        elif i in fechamento: # se é ), }, ] ou >
            if not pilha: # se a lista está vazia
                return False
            if correspondentes[i] == pilha[-1]:
                pilha.pop()

    return not bool(pilha)
```

Eu criei uma lista com os caracteres de abertura, e outra com os caracteres de fechamento. Também criei um dicionário contendo os caracteres de fechamento como chave, e o valor é o respectivo caractere de abertura. Ou seja, o dicionário é o mesmo que `{ ')': '(', ']': '[', '}': '{', '>': '<' }`: ele mapeia cada caractere de fechamento para o seu respectivo caractere de abertura, assim a verificação fica mais simples e legível do usar um `if` com várias condições.

Para criá-lo, usei a sintaxe de [*dict comprehension*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052). Também usei a [função `zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) para percorrer duas listas ao mesmo tempo (`abertura` e `fechamento`).

Em seguida, eu faço o `for` pelos caracteres da string, e caso o caractere seja de abertura (`if i in abertura`), eu adiciono-o na lista.

Se for um caractere de fechamento (`elif i in fechamento`), primeiro eu [verifico se a lista está vazia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53522) (`if not pilha`). Se eu caio neste caso (é um caractere de fechamento **e** a lista está vazia), quer dizer que não existe o caractere de abertura correspondente, então eu já posso retornar `False` imediatamente, **pois neste ponto já está claro que a expressão não está bem formada e nem adianta verificar o restante da string**.

Se a lista não estiver vazia, eu verifico se o último caractere da lista (`pilha[-1]`) é igual à abertura correspondente ao caractere de fechamento (`correspondentes[i]`).

No final, eu retorno `True` se a lista estiver vazia, e `False` caso contrário. No caso, eu converto a lista para *booleano*, e esta conversão segue as regras do [*Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), no qual listas vazias são consideradas valores "falsos" (leia mais sobre valores *truthy* e *falsy* [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/112052) **←** este link é sobre JavaScript, mas a ideia geral é a mesma no Python).

---

Os caracteres de abertura e fechamento também poderiam estar em strings em vez de listas:

```
abertura = '([{<'
fechamento = ')]}>'
```

Já que `if i in abertura` e `elif i in fechamento` funcionariam da mesma maneira, para verificar se `i` é um desses caracteres. O importante é que os caracteres correspondentes estejam nas mesmas posições, para que o dicionário `correspondentes` seja montado corretamente.

---

Qualquer outro caractere que não seja de abertura ou fechamento é ignorado (seu primeiro `if` dá a entender que é isso que você quer).

Repare que não precisei colocar um `if` específico para testar se o caractere não é abertura nem fechamento. Se ele for abertura, cai no `if i in abertura`, e se for fechamento, cai no `elif i in fechamento`. Se não for nenhum dos dois, não faz nada e vai para a próxima iteração do `for`.

Testando:

```
print(balanceada('() ')) # True
print(balanceada('()[]{}<>')) # True
print(balanceada('(x)[y]{z}a<b>')) # True
print(balanceada('({})<[]a bc([{<<  xyz >( ) >   }])>')) # True
print(balanceada(' ( { [[]] <> } ) ')) # True
print(balanceada('(}')) # False
print(balanceada('())')) # False
print(balanceada('(  [ )')) # False
print(balanceada('(}()')) # False
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na linha 9 em `pilha[-1]`. Em algum momento da execução do programa, a lista `pilha` está vazia, ou seja, você está tentando acessar um item que não existe, gerando o `IndexError`.

Tente melhorar as suas condicionais de forma que a lista `pilha` não fique fazia ao chegar na condicional da linha 9 ou então acrescente à sua condição `len(pilha) > 0`. Exemplo:

```
def balanceada(string):
    pilha = []
    for i in string:
        if i != '(' or i != '[' or i != '{' or i != '<' or i != ')' or i != ']' or i != '}' or i != '>':
            pass
        if i == '(' or i == '[' or i == '{' or i == "<":
            pilha.append(i)
        else:
            if len(pilha) > 0 and (i == ")" and pilha[-1] == "(") or (i == "]" and pilha[-1] == "[") or (i == "}" and pilha[-1] == "{") or (i == ">" and pilha[-1] == "<"):
                pilha.pop()
            else:
                return False
    if len(pilha) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Troque o return da função apresentada pelo hkotsubo pelo seguinte:

```
    return ('%s -> \'%s\'' % (not bool(pilha), string))
```

assim você poderá ver a string que foi passada para a função.