# Usar switch para testar se um valor está entre uma faixa de valores

Tags: javascript, switch

Não estou conseguindo comparar os valores dentro de um `switch case`:

```
function determinarGeracao(anoDeNascimento) {

/*
Complete a função onde voce deve comparar o
* valor da variavel anoDeNascimento e atribuir na variavel 
*resultado uma das seuintes condições.
 * Geração silenciosa: para os nascidos até o ano de 1945;
 * Boomers: para os que nasceram depois de 1945 até 1964;
 * Geração X: para os que nasceram depois de 1964 até 1980;
 * Millennials: para os que nasceram depois de 1981 até 1996;
 * Geração Z: para os que nasceram depois de 1996;
 *
 */


  let resultado;
  anoDeNascimento = 1980;

  switch(anoDeNascimento ){

      case anoDeNascimento == 1945:
      resultado = console.log('Geração silenciosa');
      break;

      case anoDeNascimento > 1945 && anoDeNascimento <=1964:
      resultado = console.log('Boomers');
      break;

      case anoDeNascimento > 1964 && anoDeNascimento <=1980:
      resultado = console.log('Geração X');
      break;

      case anoDeNascimento > 1980 && anoDeNascimento <=1996:
      resultado = console.log('Millennials');
      break;

      case anoDeNascimento > 1996 :
      resultado = console.log('Geração Z');
      break;
      default:
     resultado =  console.log('opção errada');
  }
  return resultado;
```

Comment: Use `if`/`else` em vez de `switch`, simples assim :-)

Comment: De curiosidade, qual seria a razão de ter escolhido justamente o `switch` para este cenário?

Comment: Coloque um parênteses nas condições de teste: `( )` que irá funcionar. Exemplo: `( anoDeNascimento == 1945 )`

Comment: @IvanFerrer Tem certeza? https://jsfiddle.net/jk5a8zg7/2/

Comment: Então, [tenta assim](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/xoj3a5su/), deve funcionar.

Comment: Na verdade, o switch case está sendo usado de forma errada, nem seria necessário, porque é um comparador de caso... realmente não funcionará desta maneira, eu achei que por funcionar no php também funcionaria em javascript. O acontece na verdade é que o switch já está fazendo o papel do if... [ideone](https://ideone.com/Ui5QTV)

Comment: @IvanFerrer Na verdade em PHP "funciona" por coincidência, pois o [`switch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) usa o [*loose comparison*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose), segundo o qual qualquer número maior que zero é igual a TRUE, por isso "funciona". Mas nem sempre vai funcionar: https://ideone.com/Zuq8iD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente assim, vai funcionar:

```
  function determinarGeracao(anoDeNascimento) {

/*
Complete a função onde voce deve comparar o
* valor da variavel anoDeNascimento e atribuir na variavel 
*resultado uma das seguintes condições.
 * Geração silenciosa: para os nascidos até o ano de 1945;
 * Boomers: para os que nasceram depois de 1945 até 1964;
 * Geração X: para os que nasceram depois de 1964 até 1980;
 * Millennials: para os que nasceram depois de 1981 até 1996;
 * Geração Z: para os que nasceram depois de 1996;
 *
 */


  let resultado;
 // anoDeNascimento = 1980;


     if (anoDeNascimento > 1945 && anoDeNascimento <=1964) {
         anoDeNascimento = 'boomers';
     }
     if (anoDeNascimento > 1964 && anoDeNascimento <=1980) {
         anoDeNascimento = 'geracaox';
     }
     if (anoDeNascimento > 1980 && anoDeNascimento <=1996) {
         anoDeNascimento = 'millennials';
     }
     if (anoDeNascimento > 1996) {
         anoDeNascimento = 'geracaox';
     }


  switch(anoDeNascimento ){


      case 1945:
      resultado = 'Geração silenciosa';
      break;

      case 'boomers':
      resultado = 'Boomers';
      break;

      case 'geracaox':
      resultado = 'Geração X';
      break;

      case 'millennials':
      resultado = 'Millennials';
      break;

      case 'geracaox' :
      resultado = 'Geração Z';
      break;
      default:
      resultado = 'opção errada';
  }
  console.log(resultado);
  return resultado;
}

  alert(determinarGeracao(1996));
```

Você também pode fazer assim (só uma ideia):

```
function determinarGeracao(ano) {

     this.mapArr = function(intervalYearsOld, year) {
          return Array(intervalYearsOld).fill(year).map((x, y) => x + y);   
     }

     var boomers =  this.mapArr(21, 1944), 
         geracao_x = this.mapArr(18, 1964), 
         millenials = this.mapArr(15,1982),
         geracao_z = this.mapArr((new Date()).getFullYear(),1996);
     var periods = [
       {"years":[1945],     "title": "Geração sileciosa"},
       {"years":boomers,    "title": "Boomers"},
       {"years":geracao_x,  "title": "Geração X"},
       {"years":millenials, "title": "Millennials"},
       {"years":geracao_z, "title": "Geração Z"}          
    ];
      for(var i in periods){
          //console.log(periods[i].years);
         if (periods[i].years.indexOf(ano) !== -1) {
             return periods[i].title;
         }
      }
     return 'Opção errada';

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Quando você faz:

```
switch(valor) {
    case outroValor:
        ....
```

A ideia é que `valor` seja comparado com `outroValor`. Mas caso `outroValor` seja uma expressão, o **resultado** desta expressão que é comparado com `valor`. Ex:

```js
let x = 1;
switch(x) {
    case x > 0:
        console.log('positivo');
        break;
    case x < 0:
        console.log('negativo');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('nenhum');
}
```

`switch(x)` vai comparar o valor de `x` (que é o número `1`) com o resultado das expressões `x > 0` e `x < 0`. Só que ambas são comparações, cujo resultado é um *booleano* (`true` ou `false`).

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Description) (e a [especificação da linguagem](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.11)), `switch` usa o [operador `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) para comparar os valores.
Como o número `1` não é um *booleano*, ele não é igual a `true`, nem a `false` (tanto `1 === true` quanto `1 === false` são falsas), e portanto ele cai no caso `default`, e o código acima imprime "nenhum".

---

Isso quer dizer que o `switch` cujas condições são resultados de uma comparação só funcionaria se a variável sendo testada for *booleana*:

```js
let x = 1;
let y = false;
switch (y) {
    case x > 0:
        console.log('positivo');
        break;
    case x < 0:
        console.log('negativo');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('nenhum');
}
```

O código acima imprime "negativo". Isso porque `switch(y)` vai primeiro comparar o valor de `y` (que é o valor *booleano* `false`) com o resultado da expressão `x > 0` (que é `true`). Depois `y` é comparado com o resultado de `x < 0` (que é `false`), e como `y` também é `false`, o código imprime "negativo".

---

Enfim, para fazer o que você precisa, use `if` e `else`:

```js
function determinarGeracao(anoDeNascimento){
    if (anoDeNascimento == 1945) {
        return 'Geração silenciosa';
    } else if (anoDeNascimento > 1945 && anoDeNascimento <= 1964) {
        return 'Boomers';
    } else if (anoDeNascimento > 1964 && anoDeNascimento <= 1980) {
        return 'Geração X';
    } else if (anoDeNascimento > 1980 && anoDeNascimento <= 1996) {
        return 'Millennials';
    } else if (anoDeNascimento > 1996) {
        return 'Geração Z';
    } else return 'opção errada';
}

console.log(determinarGeracao(1980));
```

Primeiramente, repare que não coloquei `console.log` dentro da função. `console.log` retorna `undefined`, então não faz sentido atribuir o seu retorno em uma variável. Ou você imprime, ou você retorna este valor para que seja impresso em outro lugar. Por isso a função simplesmente retorna o texto correspondente à geração.

Outro detalhe é que nesta lógica, se a pessoa nasceu antes de 1945, é considerado inválido ("opção errada"). Mas no enunciado está assim:

> Geração silenciosa: para os nascidos até o ano de 1945;

Então na verdade o código deveria estar desta forma:

```js
function determinarGeracao(anoDeNascimento){
    if (anoDeNascimento <= 1945) {
        return 'Geração silenciosa';
    }
    if (anoDeNascimento <= 1964) {
        return 'Boomers';
    }
    if (anoDeNascimento <= 1980) {
        return 'Geração X';
    }
    if (anoDeNascimento <= 1996) {
        return 'Millennials';
    }
    return 'Geração Z';
}

console.log(determinarGeracao(1980));
```

Primeiro eu testo se o ano é menor ou igual a 1945 ("Geração silenciosa"). Repare que não precisa do `else`, pois o `return` já retorna o valor e sai da função, então se entrar em algum `if`, a função já retornará algum valor e não executará os demais `if`'s.

Depois, no próximo `if` eu só verifico se o ano é menor que 1964. O `if` anterior já me garante que neste ponto da função o ano é maior que 1945 (se não fosse, teria entrado no `if` anterior e retornado), então não preciso colocar isso novamente no `if`.

O mesmo vale para os demais valores, e no último caso, da "Geração Z", nem precisa de `if`, pois se chegou até ali, é porque o ano não está em nenhum dos casos anteriores (obviamente que **não estou verificando se o `anoDeNascimento` é de fato um número**, mas você poderia incluir [essa verificação](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1303646) também).

---

Outro detalhe é que você estava fazendo isso:

```
function determinarGeracao(anoDeNascimento) {
    anoDeNascimento = 1980;
    ...
}
```

Ou seja, você recebe um valor como parâmetro da função, para logo em seguida sobrescrever este valor. Eu retirei esta linha e dentro da função uso o valor que foi passado a mesma.

---

No enunciado ainda diz:

> atribuir na variável resultado uma das seguintes condições: ...

E talvez por isso você esteja fazendo `resultado = 'alguma coisa'`. Bom, acho que isso pode estar te confundindo, pois pode dar a entender que isso deve ser feito dentro da função, como você está tentando fazer:

```
function determinarGeracao(anoDeNascimento){
    let resultado;
    if (anoDeNascimento <= 1945) {
        resultado = 'Geração silenciosa';
    }
    if (anoDeNascimento <= 1964) {
        resultado = 'Boomers';
    }
    ... etc....

    return resultado;
}
```

Mas o que eu entendi é que na verdade só precisa disso:

```
function determinarGeracao(anoDeNascimento){
    if (anoDeNascimento <= 1945) {
        return 'Geração silenciosa';
    }
    if (anoDeNascimento <= 1964) {
        return 'Boomers';
    }
    if (anoDeNascimento <= 1980) {
        return 'Geração X';
    }
    if (anoDeNascimento <= 1996) {
        return 'Millennials';
    }
    return 'Geração Z';
}

let resultado = determinarGeracao(1980);
```

A variável `resultado` recebe o retorno da função, e aí você pode fazer o que quiser com ela (imprimir com `console.log`, por exemplo).

---

Obs: indo um pouco além, números e outros tipos [*podem* ser "convertidos" para *boolean*, através de um mecanismo conhecido como coerção de tipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/112052).

Answer (score 2):

Quando for verificar se um valor ou variável está contido dentro de uma faixa, ou várias faixas, é melhor usar o operador condicional [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

```js
console.log(determinarGeracao(prompt("Entre com o ano de nascimento", 1980)));


    function determinarGeracao(anoDeNascimento) {

      if (anoDeNascimento <= 1945) return 'Geração silenciosa';
      if (anoDeNascimento > 1945 && anoDeNascimento <= 1964) return 'Boomers';
      if (anoDeNascimento > 1964 && anoDeNascimento <= 1980) return 'Geração X';
      if (anoDeNascimento > 1980 && anoDeNascimento <= 1996) return 'Millennials';
      if (anoDeNascimento > 1996) return 'Geração Z';
      return 'Entrada inválida'
    }
```

**Edição:** Como você informou seu exercício exige que seja utilizada uma variável intermediária, `resultado`. Desvantagem dessa abordagem é que cada chamada da função é gasto tempo com a alocação de memória para a variável e depois do resultado ser encontrado sem há a possibilidade de serem feitas comparações desnecessárias.

```js
console.log(determinarGeracao(prompt("Entre com o ano de nascimento", 1980)));


function determinarGeracao(anoDeNascimento) {

  let resultado = 'Entrada inválida';

  if (anoDeNascimento <= 1945) resultado = 'Geração silenciosa';
  if (anoDeNascimento > 1945 && anoDeNascimento <= 1964) resultado = 'Boomers';
  if (anoDeNascimento > 1964 && anoDeNascimento <= 1980) resultado = 'Geração X';
  if (anoDeNascimento > 1980 && anoDeNascimento <= 1996) resultado = 'Millennials';
  if (anoDeNascimento > 1996) resultado = 'Geração Z';

  return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

/* Funcionou bem, é só trocar o console log por return, que da certo, mas assim vc testa. Copia exatamente assim e testa no seu console. A diferença ai é que ele vai procurar a expressaão vverdadeira, logo quando você diz, "sistema anodenasc.. é > ou = a 1980!" ebtenda que você não pergunta, você afirma, a pergunta é em If, ai ele vai dizer, "verdade!" então vai te retornar o valor que você determinou (no caso a string 'Geração x')*/

let anoDeNascimento = 1960;
let test = true

switch(test ){

```
case anoDeNascimento == 1945:
console.log('Geração silenciosa');
break;

case anoDeNascimento > 1945 && anoDeNascimento <=1964:
console.log('Boomers');
break;

case anoDeNascimento > 1964 && anoDeNascimento <=1980:
console.log('Geração X');
break;

case anoDeNascimento > 1980 && anoDeNascimento <=1996:
console.log('Millennials');
break;

case anoDeNascimento > 1996 :
console.log('Geração Z');
break;
default:
```

console.log('opção errada');
}

Answer (score -2):

function determinarGeracao(anoDeNascimento) {

```
if (anoDeNascimento <=1945) {
    return resultado = 'Geração silenciosa';
} else if (anoDeNascimento > 1945 && anoDeNascimento <= 1964) {
    return resultado = 'Boomers';
} else if (anoDeNascimento > 1964 && anoDeNascimento <= 1980) {
    return resultado = 'Geração X';
} else if (anoDeNascimento > 1980 && anoDeNascimento <= 1996) {
    return resultado = 'Millennials';
} else if (anoDeNascimento > 1996) {
    return resultado = 'Geração Z';
}
```

console.log(determinarGeracao(1986));
console.log(resultado);

}

fiz assim e deu certo.