# Não estou passando nenhum dado na requisição mas parece que está vindo alguma informação

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Tenho um método `index` que retorna lugares (casas/apartamentos) cadastrados no site. É possível filtrar por localização e características chave se a pessoa quiser. Se não quiser, retorno tudo que existe cadastrado.

Entretanto, mesmo que eu não envie nenhum dado na requisição, o `if` que eu estou usando para verificar isso dá `true`. E nenhum lugar cadastrado está sendo retornado.

A requisição que estou fazendo: [image: não envio dados na requisicão]

O retorno que eu tenho: [image: printando na tela location e characteristics estão nulos mas mesmo assim está entrando nos if]

Código:

```
async index(req,res){
        const {location} = req.query
        const {characteristics} = req.query
        let spots

        if({location}){
            spots = await Spot.find({location: { "$regex" : location , "$options" : "i"}})//case insensitive
            console.log(' local foi informado',{location})
            if({characteristics}){
                console.log('caracteristicas foram informadas',{characteristics})
                spots = await Spot.find({characteristics: characteristics,location: { "$regex" : location , "$options" : "i"}})//case insensitive
                return res.json(spots)
            }
            console.log('não tem caracteristicas informadas, só local')
            return res.json(spots)
        }        
        spots = await Spot.find()
        return res.json(spots)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somente com o trecho de código abaixo é possível entender de onde veio o seu engano:

> ```js
> const {location} = req.query 
> const {characteristics} = req.query
> let spots
>
> if ({location}) { /** ... */ }
> ```

Nas duas primeiras linhas, você está fazendo o uso da [atribuição por desestruturação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao) para declarar as variáveis `location` e `characteristics`, presentes no objeto `req.query`. Você  poderia, inclusive, reduzir essas declarações para somente uma linha:

```js
const { location, characteristics } = req.query
```

Então, voltando ao seu código, é importante lembrar que você está declarando as variáveis `location` e `characteristics`, e não `{location}` ou `{characteristics}`, até porque as chaves (`{}`) nem são caracteres válidos para o nome de uma variável. Isso tudo faz parte da sintaxe da linguagem para que a atribuição por desestruturação seja possível. :)

Tendo isso em mente, a condicional:

> ```js
> if ({location}) { /** ... */ }
> ```

É problemática, uma vez que não está avaliando a variável `location`, mas sim um objeto que é criado com ela. Lembre-se, que como você tem a variável `location` declarada, você está criando um objeto através da abreviação do nome de propriedades. Basicamente, o que você está fazendo é o seguinte:

```js
// Você já tem a variável `location` declarada. Abaixo
// estou dando um outro nome para simplificar.
const loc = '';

// Criamos um objeto com a variável `location`.
// É o que você está fazendo no `if`.
const obj = { loc };

// Veja:
console.log(obj); // { "loc": "" }

// E você está fazendo a comparação seguinte no `if`.
// É o mesmo de: `if ({ loc }) {`
if (obj) {
  console.log('Entrei!'); // Será logado.
}
```

Isso faz com que você sempre *entre* no `if`, já que o objeto criado no "local de avaliação do `if`" sempre será verdadeiro. Em suma, você não está avaliando, de fato, a variável, mas sim um objeto criado com ela.

O correto seria:

```js
if (location) {
  // Seu código...
}
```

Você poderia até fazer uma comparação explícita, como `location !== ""`, mas vale lembrar que strings vazias são consideradas valores *falsey*. Desse modo:

```js
// Strings vazias são avaliadas como valores falsey.
if ('') {
  console.log('If 1.'); // Não será logado.
}

// Strings não vazias são avaliadas como valores truthy.
if (' ') {
  console.log('If 2.');; // Será logado.
}
```

Para saber mais, leia também [a documentação sobre inicialização de objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Inicializador_Objeto). Leia também sobre [valores *falsey* e *truthy*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271693/valores-truthy-e-falsy).

Answer (score 0):

O que ocorre é que o seu IF está verificando se foi enviado um parâmetro chamado "characteristics" e "location". O parâmetro foi enviado, o que ocorre é que o conteúdo está vazio.

Tem que ajustar para verificar se o parâmetro existe e se não está vazio. Seria algo como:

```js
async index(req,res){
        const {location, characteristics} = req.query
        let spots

        if(location){
            if (location !== ""){
                spots = await Spot.find({location: { "$regex" : location , "$options" : "i"}})//case insensitive
                console.log(' local foi informado',{location})
                if(characteristics){
                    if(characteristics !== ""){
                        console.log('caracteristicas foram informadas',{characteristics})
                        spots = await Spot.find({characteristics: characteristics,location: { "$regex" : location , "$options" : "i"}})//case insensitive
                        return res.json(spots)
                    }
                }
                console.log('não tem caracteristicas informadas, só local')
                return res.json(spots)
            }
        }        
        spots = await Spot.find()
        return res.json(spots)
}
```