# Reduzir a quantidade de if em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, if

Estou construindo uma aplicação no site de aves. Dentro do site terá um artigo informando as possíveis genéticas que será gerada através de um acasalamento de duas raças diferentes.

**Exemplo:** **Ring Neck - Albino** x **Ring Neck - Azul** pode gerar **Ring Neck - Violeta**.

Para isso criei no HTML um select listando todos os machos, e dependendo do macho escolhido será gerado uma outra lista(outro select abaixo), com todas as fêmeas que faz par com ele.

Depois de **selecionado** o **macho** e a **fêmea**, quando clicar no **botão VERIFICAR**, ele irá trazer dentro de um textarea o resultado.

**PROBLEMA**

Como são várias raças, existem várias validações, gostaria da ajuda de vocês se consigo reduzir a quantidade de if, else if.

```js
var box01  = document.getElementById("box01");
var box02  = document.getElementById("box02");
var txtArea = document.getElementById("txtArea");

function myChange(){
    box02.innerHTML = "";
    box02.removeAttribute("disabled");

    if(box01.value == "nenhum"){
        box02.setAttribute("disabled");
    }

    if(box01.value == "albino"){
        var optionArray = ["0|Nenhum","albino|Albino","azul|Azul",
        "canela|Canela","cremino|Cremino","turquesa-azul|Turquesa Azul","verde-azul|Verde/Azul","lutino|Lutino","lutino-azul|Lutino/Azul","turquesa-cinza|Turquesa Cinza","skyblue|SkyBlue"];
    }
    else if(box01.value == "azul"){
        var optionArray = ["0|Nenhum","azul|Azul","lutino|Lutino","lutino-azul|Lutino/Azul","albino|Albino","cinza|Cinza","verde-azul|Verde/Azul","verde-cinza-azul|Verde Cinza/Azul","turquesa-azul|Turquesa Azul","silver|Silver","skyblue|SkyBlue","turquesa-cinza|Turquesa Cinza","cremino|Cremino"];
    }
    else if(box01.value == "canela"){
        var optionArray = ["0|Nenhum","cinza|Cinza"];
    }
    else if(box01.value == "canela-azul"){
        var optionArray = ["0|Nenhum","skyblue|SkyBlue","cinza|Cinza","azul|Azul","canela-verde-cinza-azul|Canela Verde Cinza/Azul","silver|Silver"];
    }       
    for(var option in optionArray){
        // Método .sort() ordena o elementos do próprio array.
       //  Método foi utilizado para organizar a exibição da box02(fêmeas) em ordem alfabetica. 
            optionArray.sort(); 
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");

            newOption.value = pair[0];
            newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];

            box02.options.add(newOption);       
    } 
}
function myFunction(){

    // Validação Albino
    if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "0"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "verde-azul"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Verde/Azul\nM Azul\nF Lutino/Azul\nF Albino";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "albino"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Albino\nF Albino";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "azul"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Azul\nF Albino";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "cremino"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Cremino\nM Albino\n\nF Cremino\nF Albino";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "turquesa-azul"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Turquesa/Azul\nM Azul\n\nF Cremino\nF Albino";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "lutino"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Lutino/Azul\nF Lutino/Azul";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "lutino-azul"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Lutino/Azul\nM Albino\n\nF Lutino/Azul\nF Albino";
    }

}
```

```html
<form>
    <div id="container-form">
        <label for="box01">Macho</label>
        <select id="box01" name="box01" onchange="myChange()">
            <option value="nenhum">Nenhum</option>
            <option value="albino">Ring Neck - Albino</option>
            <option value="azul">Ring Neck - Azul</option>
            <option value="canela">Ring Neck - Canela</option>
            <option value="canela-azul">Ring Neck - Canela Azul</option>
            <option value="canela-verde-cinza">Ring Neck - Canela Verde Cinza</option>
            <option value="cinza">Ring Neck - Cinza</option>
            <option value="cremino">Ring Neck - Cremino</option>
            <option value="lutino">Ring Neck - Lutino</option>
            <option value="silver">Ring Neck - Silver</option>
            <option value="skyblue">Ring Neck - SkyBlue</option>
            <option value="turquesa-azul">Ring Neck - Turquesa Azul</option>
            <option value="turquesa-cinza">Ring Neck - Turquesa Cinza</option>
            <option value="turquesa-skyblue">Ring Neck - Turquesa SkyBlue</option>
            <option value="turquesa-silver">Ring Neck - Turquesa Silver</option>
            <option value="verde-cinza">Ring Neck - Verde Cinza</option>
            <option value="verde">Ring Neck - Verde</option>
            <option value="pallids">Ring Neck - Pallids</option>
        </select>
        <label for="box01">Fêmea</label>
        <select id="box02" disabled>

        </select>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Verificar</button>
    </div>
    <textarea id="txtArea" rows="10" cols="29" disabled></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para atualizar a lista de opções de fêmeas, você pode criar um mapeamento de machos para as respectivas possibilidades de fêmeas, algo assim:

```
var mapMachoFemeas = {
    "albino": [ {"valor": "albino", "texto": "Albino"}, {"valor": "verde-azul", "texto": "Verde/Azul"} ],
    "azul": [ {"valor": "lutino-azul", "texto": "Lutino/Azul"}, {"valor": "skyblue", "texto": "SkyBlue"} ],
    "canela": [ {"valor": "cinza", "texto": "Cinza"} ],
    "canela-azul": [ {"valor": "cinza", "texto": "Cinza"}, {"valor": "canela-verde-cinza-azul", "texto": "Canela Verde Cinza/Azul"} ]
};
```

Deixei o exemplo acima incompleto, mas a ideia básica é: para cada tipo de macho ("albino", "azul", etc), existe um array com possíveis fêmeas. E cada elemento do array de fêmeas é um objeto que possui as chaves "valor" e "texto", que são usadas para construir as opções do `select`. Veja que não precisa incluir a opção "Nenhum", pois se ela sempre é adicionada, basta adicioná-la toda vez que tiver que mudar.

Ficaria assim (deixei incompleto, com somente algumas opções, para ficar mais curto, mas basta adicionar todas as opções no `mapMachoFemeas` - e já deixe-as em ordem, assim você não precisa chamar `sort` toda hora):

```js
var box01  = document.getElementById("box01");
var box02  = document.getElementById("box02");
var txtArea = document.getElementById("txtArea");

// mapeia cada macho para as respectivas opções de fêmeas
var mapMachoFemeas = {
    "albino": [ {"valor": "albino", "texto": "Albino"}, {"valor": "verde-azul", "texto": "Verde/Azul"} ],
    "azul": [ {"valor": "lutino-azul", "texto": "Lutino/Azul"}, {"valor": "skyblue", "texto": "SkyBlue"} ],
    "canela": [ {"valor": "cinza", "texto": "Cinza"} ],
    "canela-azul": [ {"valor": "cinza", "texto": "Cinza"}, {"valor": "canela-verde-cinza-azul", "texto": "Canela Verde Cinza/Azul"} ]
};

function novaOpcao(valor, texto) {
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = valor;
    newOption.label = texto;
    return newOption;
}
function atualizarFemeas(){
    box02.innerHTML = "";
    box02.removeAttribute("disabled");

    var macho = box01.value;
    if (macho == "nenhum") {
        box02.setAttribute("disabled");
    } else if (mapMachoFemeas[macho]) {
        box02.options.add(novaOpcao("0", "Nenhum"));       
        for (var femea of mapMachoFemeas[macho]) {
            box02.options.add(novaOpcao(femea.valor, femea.texto));       
        }
    }
}

function verificarCruzamentos(){
    // Validação Albino
    if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "0"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "verde-azul"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Verde/Azul\nM Azul\nF Lutino/Azul\nF Albino";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "albino"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Albino\nF Albino";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "azul"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Azul\nF Albino";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "cremino"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Cremino\nM Albino\n\nF Cremino\nF Albino";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "turquesa-azul"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Turquesa/Azul\nM Azul\n\nF Cremino\nF Albino";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "lutino"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Lutino/Azul\nF Lutino/Azul";
    }
    else if(box01.value == "albino" && box02.value == "lutino-azul"){
        txtArea.innerHTML = "M Lutino/Azul\nM Albino\n\nF Lutino/Azul\nF Albino";
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div id="container-form">
        <label for="box01">Macho</label>
        <select id="box01" name="box01" onchange="atualizarFemeas()">
            <option value="nenhum">Nenhum</option>
            <option value="albino">Ring Neck - Albino</option>
            <option value="azul">Ring Neck - Azul</option>
            <option value="canela">Ring Neck - Canela</option>
            <option value="canela-azul">Ring Neck - Canela Azul</option>
        </select>
        <label for="box01">Fêmea</label>
        <select id="box02" disabled>

        </select>
        <button type="button" onclick="verificarCruzamentos()">Verificar</button>
    </div>
    <textarea id="txtArea" rows="10" cols="29" disabled></textarea>
</form>
```

Também mudei os nomes da funções para algo mais significativo (pois `myFunction` é muito genérico e não ajuda a indicar o que a função faz). Pode parecer um detalhe bobo, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

---

Já para a função que mostra o resultado, eu não entendi a lógica das combinações, mas você poderia ter uma ideia similar: criar um mapeamento com as possibilidades e consultá-lo com os valores indicados. Algo assim:

```
var cruzamentos = {
    "albino": {
        "verde-azul": "resultado do cruzamento de macho albino com fêmea verde-azul",
        "cremino": "resultado do cruzamento de macho albino com fêmea cremino"
    },
    "azul": {
        "verde-azul": "resultado do cruzamento de macho azul com fêmea verde-azul",
        "cremino": "resultado do cruzamento de macho cremino com fêmea cremino"
    }
};


function verificarCruzamentos(){
    if (cruzamentos[box1.value] && cruzamentos[box1.value][box02.value]) {
        txtArea.innerHTML = cruzamentos[box1.value][box02.value];
    } else {
        txtArea.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Estou sugerindo isso porque, como já disse, não entendi muito bem a lógica para gerar os resultados. Se tiver uma regra mais "exata", daria para fazer algo mais "esperto", mas assim já elimina esse monte de `if` e deixa as coisas mais organizadas (se precisar acrescentar mais alguma combinação, basta mudar os mapeamentos).

Comment: O Final seria uma outra validação. Exemplo  vamos supor que no primeiro campo "select macho" escolheu albino e no segundo "select femea" escolheu azul .... ai dentro do textarea teria que dar o resultado do cruzamento da geneticas dos dois.  Neste caso eu teria que criar outro objeto?

Comment: @GabrielMariano Então, seria esse objeto `cruzamentos` que eu falei no final

Comment: ah saquei, muito obrigado! Vou fazer um teste.

Comment: @GabrielMariano Blz. Não esqueça que, **se** a resposta resolver o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Comment: Pode deixar ;] ! Estou realizando os testes.

Comment: Desculpe pela minha ignorância @hkotsubo, mas eu não consegui entender a function verificarCruzamentos( ) ...sendo mais especifico, não consegui entender como ele está validando o " cruzamentos[box1.value][box02.value] "

Comment: @GabrielMariano Ele verifica se existe o valor no objeto `cruzamentos`. Por exemplo, se vc escolher "nenhum", o value dos boxes será `0` e ao buscar `cruzamentos[0]` não encontrará nada (e aí ele cai no else) - editei agora pra mudar a verificação, pois tanto o macho quanto a fêmea pode ser "nenhum", então o `if` tem que tratar esses 2 casos

Comment: @GabrielMariano Complementando, esse `if` funciona porque valores nulos são considerados `false`, por isso vc pode testar qualquer objeto em um if, veja mais sobre isso aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/112052

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!