# Por que esse codigo sempre retorna False?

Tags: javascript, if

Alguém consegue me explicar por que sempre retorna false????

```
function ValidationProcessDoc( ext ){
    if ( ext === 'TXT' || 'DOC' || 'XLS' || 'PPT' ) {
        return false;
    }
    else if ( ext === 'PDF' || 'HTM' || 'HTML' ) {
        console.log(ext);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: [O que são os valores truthy e falsy?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/100416)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ele sempre retorna falso, pois a primeira condição sempre será verdadeira, independente do parâmetro que você passe.

Isso acontece por conta da seguinte verificação:

```
if ( ext === 'TXT' || 'DOC' || 'XLS' || 'PPT' ) {
```

Caso o valor de `ext` seja diferente de `'TXT'`, as demais condições todas são verdadeiras, pois javascript compreende que uma string não vazia é verdadeiro, veja esse exemplo:

```js
if ("Teste") {
  console.log("(\"Teste\") = Verdadeiro");
}

if ("") {
  console.log("(\"\") = Verdadeiro");
}
```

Perceba que se eu faço uma `if` utilizando uma string com valor, a condição é atendida.

---

Caso queira corrigir seu código de forma simples, faça as demais verificações utilizando a variável `ext` novamente:

```js
function ValidationProcessDoc( ext ){
  if ( ext === 'TXT' || ext === 'DOC' || ext === 'XLS' || ext === 'PPT' ) {
      return false;
  }
  else if ( ext === 'PDF' || ext === 'HTM' || ext === 'HTML' ) {
      return true;
  }
  else {
      return false;
  }
}

console.log( ValidationProcessDoc('PDF') );
console.log( ValidationProcessDoc('TXT') );
console.log( ValidationProcessDoc('XISTO') );
```

---

Você pode alterar sua função, deixando ela bem mais simples, retorno diretamente a verificação dos tipos que retornam `true`:

```js
function ValidationProcessDoc( ext ){
  return ext === 'PDF' || ext === 'HTM' || ext === 'HTML';
}

console.log( ValidationProcessDoc('PDF') );
console.log( ValidationProcessDoc('TXT') );
console.log( ValidationProcessDoc('XISTO') );
```