# Como utilizar o 'else if' corretamente?

Tags: javascript, if

Construi uma função chamada `min` que retorna o menor número que é passado em um de seus dois argumentos. Quando os números são iguais ela retorna `null`. Consegui fazer o código funcionar da seguinte maneira:

```
function min(a,b){
    if(a != b){
        if(a<b){
            return a; 
        }else{
            return b; 
        }
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Inicialmente eu fiz o código da seguinte forma:

```
function min(a, b){
    if(a<b){
        return a; 
    }else if(a = b){
        console.log('They are the same')
    }else{
        return b;
    }
}
```

Só que ele não funcionou, ele retorna corretamente somente o primeiro `if(a<b)`, caso os argumentos não caiam nesse primeiro caso, a função retorna continuamente `null`.

Qual o erro de lógica estou cometendo nesse segundo caso?

Comment: Comparação entre valores é realizada com `==` e não com `=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `=` é o [operador de atribuição](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment), então `a = b` está na verdade setando o valor da variável `a`, que passa a ser o mesmo valor de `b`. Em seguida, esse valor é testado de acordo com [essas regras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/112052) (e como qualquer número diferente de zero é considerado "true", quaisquer valores de `b` que sejam diferentes de zero fará com que entre neste `if` - caso não tenha entrado no `if` anterior, claro).

Por exemplo:

```js
let a;
let b = 10;

if (a = b) { // a recebe o valor de b
    console.log(a); // 10
}
```

`a = b` faz com que `a` receba o valor de `b`, que é `10`.

Então no fundo estamos testando `if (10)`, e como números diferentes de zero são considerados verdadeiros, ele entra no `if` e imprime o valor de `a` (no caso, `10`).

Então para corrigir, você pode usar `==` (o [operador de igualdade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality)) ou `===` ([operador de igualdade estrita](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)). A diferença é que o primeiro pode fazer conversão de tipos entre os valores (por exemplo, `'10' == 10` é considerado "true"), enquanto o segundo não faz essa conversão e verifica se os valores também são do mesmo tipo (ex: `'10' === 10` é "false", mas `10 === 10` e `1 + 9 === 10` são "true"). [Leia aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494) para mais detalhes.

---

Dito isso, se a ideia é retornar o menor valor (ou `null` se ambos forem iguais), nem precisaria testar igualdade, daria para fazer assim:

```js
function min(a, b) {
    if (a < b) return a;
    if (a > b) return b;
    return null;
}

console.log(min(1, 2)); // 1
console.log(min(10, 2)); // 2
console.log(min(2, 2)); // null
```

O [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) retorna o valor indicado e **sai da função** (ou seja, se chegou em um `return`, ela não executa o restante do código da função). Por isso nem precisa do `else`.

Se entrar no primeiro `if` é porque `a` é menor, então retorna ele e nem precisa executar o resto. Se não entrou nesse `if`, é porque `a` é maior ou igual a `b`.

Se entrar no segundo `if` é porque `b` é menor, então retorna ele e nem precisa executar o resto.

Se não entrar em nenhum dos `if`'s, é porque `a` e `b` são iguais, então eu posso retornar `null` sem nem precisar de outro `if` ali (afinal, se não entrou em nenhum `if` é porque `a` não é menor e nem maior que `b`, então a única alternativa que sobrou é que são iguais, e por isso nem precisa testar isso de novo, é redundante e desnecessário).

---

Outro detalhe é que eu não gosto da ideia de uma função que, dependendo do caso, retorna algo **ou** imprime algo e não retorna nada (que é o que você tentou fazer no segundo código).

Eu prefiro que a função sempre retorne algo, e quem a chamou que faça o que quiser com o valor retornado (inclusive imprimir uma mensagem, se for o caso):

```js
function min(a, b) {
    if (a < b) return a;
    if (a > b) return b;
    return null;
}

let result = min(2, 2);
if (result === null) {
    console.log('Não tem menor, os números são iguais');
} else {
    console.log(`O menor número é ${result}`);
}
```

Desta forma você separa bem as responsabilidades: a função só retorna o resultado (o menor dos números, ou `null` se forem iguais), e quem chamou a função toma alguma ação conforme o resultado - podendo inclusive imprimir a mensagem, e apesar de parecer que dá no mesmo, não dá, porque assim você não fica dependente da mensagem que estiver dentro da função e pode tomar a ação que quiser em cada caso (por exemplo, se eu não quiser imprimir nenhuma mensagem, ou fazer qualquer outra coisa, etc).

---

E só pra constar, quando uma função não encontra nenhum `return`, [ela acaba retornando `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Description). Ou seja, nesta função:

```js
function min(a, b){
    if (a < b){
        return a; 
    } else if (a = b) {
        console.log('They are the same');
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}
console.log(min(2, 1)); // undefined
```

Como `a` é maior que `b`, ele não entra no primeiro `if`. Aí no `else if` acontece o que já foi explicado: `a` recebe o valor de `b`, e como este não é zero, é avaliado como "true". Então entra neste `if`, imprime a mensagem "They are the same" e como nenhum `return` é executado, a função retorna `undefined` (e não `null`, como você afirmou, pois [eles não são a mesma coisa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5076944)).

Answer (score 0):

Pedro faltou somente o == no seu else if.

Em vez de comparar com o == você estava atribuindo com o =.

Segue código abaixo com a correção.

```
function min(a, b){
    if(a<b){
        return a; 
    }else if(a == b){
        console.log('They are the same')
    }else{
        return b;
    }
}
```