# por que o meu else não funciona?

Tags: javascript, else

```
const alun = document.querySelector("#bottomaluno")

alun.addEventListener('click', addaluno)

function addaluno() { 

    if(display = 'none') { 
        document.querySelector("#alunos").style.display = 'block';
    } else{
        document.querySelector("#alunos").style.display = 'none';
    }
 }
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como utilizar o 'else if' corretamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/470618/como-utilizar-o-else-if-corretamente)

Answer (score 3):

Porque **um** sinal de igual é de atribuição de valor e não de comparação, para ser dfe comparação tem que usar 2 sinais de igual, assim:

```
if(display == 'none') {
```

Comment: mesmo assim não funciona o único formato que funcionou foi com =, com dois "==" da esse erro  Uncaught ReferenceError: display is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.addaluno (addfield.js:6)

Comment: @Pedro isso ai é outro erro e não é igual ao código mostrado da pergunta.

Comment: é exatamente o mesmo código, quando eu utilizo = funciona somente o if, quando eu utilizo ou == ou === da esse erro de display não definido e não funciona nem o if e nem o else

Comment: Caro @Pedro a varivel display não existe, não faz parte do código citado acima, ou então o código esta simplesmente todo errado.

Comment: então ele está todo errado :(

Answer (score 1):

Ao usar:

```
display = 'none'
```

você está atribuindo o valor 'none' a display, o que não vai funcionar
O correto seria comparar usando:

```
display == 'none'
```

Ainda assim você estaria comparando somente o valor, e não o tipo, então eu recomendaria usar:

```
display === 'none'
```

Comment: mesmo assim não funciona o único formato que funcionou foi com =, com dois "=="  ou com três "===" da esse erro " Uncaught ReferenceError: display is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.addaluno", ps não alterei em nada o código.

Answer (score -2):

" = " atribuição,
" == " igualdade,
" === " Estritamente igual.

`display == 'none'`

Comment: mesmo assim não funciona o único formato que funcionou foi com =, com dois "=="  ou com três "===" da esse erro " Uncaught ReferenceError: display is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.addaluno", ps não alterei em nada o código.