# Como fazer comparação entre 3 variaveis?

Tags: java

Quero fazer um algoritmo que calcule qual dos 3 triângulos tem o maior perímetro, porém minha logica não está funcionando.

```
import entities.Triangle;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class OrientaçãoObjetos {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
       
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        Triangle x,y,z;
        x = new Triangle();
        y = new Triangle();
        z = new Triangle();
        
        System.out.println("Enter the mensures of triangules X: ");
        x.a = sc.nextDouble();
        x.b = sc.nextDouble();
        x.c = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the mensures of triangules Y: ");
        y.a = sc.nextDouble();
        y.b = sc.nextDouble();
        y.c = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the mensures of triangules Z: ");
        z.a = sc.nextDouble();
        z.b = sc.nextDouble();
        z.c = sc.nextDouble();
        
        Double p = (x.a + x.b + x.c) / 2.0;
        double areaX = Math.sqrt(p * (p -x.a) * (p- x.b)*(p - x.c));
        
        p = (y.a + y.b + y.c) / 2.0;
        double areaY = Math.sqrt(p * (p -x.a) * (p-x.b)*(p - x.c));

        p = (z.a + z.b + z.c) / 2.0;
        double areaZ = Math.sqrt(p * (p -z.a) * (p-z.b)*(p - z.c));
        
        System.out.printf("Triangle X area: %.4f%n", areaX);
        System.out.printf("Triangle Y area: %.4f%n", areaY);
        System.out.printf("Triangle z area: %.4f%n", areaZ);
        
        if (areaX> areaY && areaZ){
            System.out.println("Larger area: X");
        }else if(areaY>areaZ && areaX){
            System.out.println("Larger area: Y");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Larger area: Z");
        }
        
        sc.close();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, você está calculando as áreas - e não os perímetros, como foi dito na pergunta - mas de qualquer forma, a ideia abaixo seria a mesma.

O problema está nesta condição:

```
if (areaX > areaY && areaZ)
```

Isso **não** está comparando se `areaX` é ao mesmo tempo maior que `areaY` e `areaZ`. Na verdade você está tentando testar duas condições:

- se `areaX` é maior que `areaY`
- se `areaZ`

A segunda "condição" não é bem uma condição porque `areaZ` é um `double`, mas as condições de um `if` devem ser valores *booleanos* (existem linguagens que permitem outros valores em contextos *booleanos* - [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/112052) - mas não é o caso do Java). Tanto que esse `if` nem compila.

---

Sendo assim, para testar se um valor é maior que todos os outros, você deve explicitamente colocar estas condições no `if`:

```
if (areaX > areaY && areaX > areaZ) {
    System.out.println("Larger area: X");
} else if (areaY > areaX && areaY > areaZ) {
    System.out.println("Larger area: Y");
} else {
    System.out.println("Larger area: Z");
}
```

---

Vale notar que você está usando os valores de `x` para calcular a área de `y`:

```
double areaY = Math.sqrt(p * (p -x.a) * (p-x.b)*(p - x.c));
```

Ou seja, deveria ser:

```
// usar y em vez de x
double areaY = Math.sqrt(p * (p - y.a) * (p - y.b) * (p - y.c));
```

---

Claro que há outras melhorias. Por exemplo, a própria classe `Triangle` poderia ser capaz de calcular sua própria área:

```
public class Triangle {
    private double a, b, c;

    public Triangle(double a, double b, double c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public double area() {
        double p = (a + b + c) / 2.0;
        return Math.sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c));
    }
}
```

Também mudei o construtor para receber os valores dos lados, pois entendo que não faz sentido criar um triângulo sem ter os lados (ou seja, não faz muito sentido fazer `new Triangulo()` e só setar os lados depois, crie um triângulo somente se já tiver os 3 lados) - veja mais sobre o assunto em [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052) - então ficaria assim:

```
System.out.println("Enter the mensures of triangules X: ");
Triangle x = new Triangle(sc.nextDouble(), sc.nextDouble(), sc.nextDouble());

double areaX = x.area();
```

Enfim, tem várias outras coisas para melhorar, mas creio que já foge demais ao escopo da pergunta. O principal (verificar o maior valor entre 3 valores diferentes) já está resolvido acima.

Answer (score 1):

Boas, o meu conhecimento em java é pouco ou nada, mas parece-me que você tem que comparar todas as variáveis, e no seu código parece-me que elas não estão a ser todas a ser comparadas. Tomando o seu código simples de lógica:

```
    if (areaX > areaY && areaX > areaZ){
        System.out.println("Larger area: X");
    }else if(areaY > areaX && areaY > areaZ){
        System.out.println("Larger area: Y");
    }else if(areaZ > areaX && areaZ > areaY){
        System.out.println("Larger area: Z");
    }
```