# Como declarar que um objeto de um array em JavaScript está vazio

Tags: javascript, array

Fiz um programinha para simular a administração de um estacionamento. O `console.log` apresenta a quantidade de vagas e  quais carros estão nessa vaga. Porém eu fiz 4 vagas com 4 carros, e queria fazer 7 vagas com 3 delas estando vazia para o `console.log` apresentar "a vaga 5 está vazia" caso esteja vazia.

Código:

```js
let vagas = ['Fiat, Placa ABC-0123' , 'HB20, Placa ACB-0213' , 'Palio, Placa BCA-3210' , 'Kadett, CBA-2031', '']

console.log(`No estacionamento tem ${vagas.length} vagas`)
for (let lugar = 0; lugar < vagas.length; lugar++){
    console.log(`Na vaga ${lugar + 1} está o Automóvel ${vagas[lugar]} `)  
}
```

Comment: Quando nao estiver carro na vaga, voce quer mostrar no console algo como `A vaga 5 está vazia`, seria isso? pois nao entendi muito bem sua pergunta.

Comment: exato!  perdão vou editar a pergunta mas é isso mesmo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendo em vista que strings vazias (`""`) em JavaScript são valores *falsy*, você pode utilizar `vagas[lugar]` diretamente no `if` sem a necessidade de nenhum tipo de comparação.

Isso acontece porque o `if`, ao testar sua expressão, verifica se o valor pode ser convertido para o booleano correspondente. Como `Boolean("")` (note a string vazia no primeiro argumento) avalia para `false`, no caso da vaga estar "vazia", ele não "entrará no `if`".

Saiba mais sobre valores *truthy* e *falsy* [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271693/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-valores-truthy-e-falsy).

Assim:

```
if (vagas[lugar]) {
  // A vaga está usada...
} else {
  // A vaga está vazia...
}
```

A vantagem disso é que seu array pode conter outros valores *falsy*, que também serão tidos como uma vaga vazia. Por exemplo, `null`, `undefined`, `false` etc.

Temos, pois:

```js
let vagas = [
  null, undefined, '', // <--- Todos os valores desta linha serão vistos como vaga vazia.
  'Fiat, Placa ABC-0123' , 'HB20, Placa ACB-0213' ,
  'Palio, Placa BCA-3210', 'Kadett, CBA-2031'
];

console.log(`No estacionamento tem ${vagas.length} vagas`);

for (let lugar = 0; lugar < vagas.length; lugar++) {
  if (vagas[lugar]) {
    console.log(`Na vaga ${lugar + 1} está o Automóvel ${vagas[lugar]}.`);  
  } else {
    console.log(`Vaga ${lugar + 1} está vazia.`);
  }
}
```

---

<sup>Uma outra opção é comparar o valor literalmente com uma string vazia, conforme sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/483634/69296).</sup>

Comment: Muito bom, mas sabe o que reparei? Deveria ter um `if` pra quando for `" "` (com espaco), se nao, vamos ter um comportamento inesperado XD. Eu usaria regex, mas nao vem ao caso :)

Comment: @CmteCardeal, realmente, mas se fosse assim, teria que se fazer uma verificação para cada quantidade de espaços diferentes. Poderia também fazer `"   ".trim()`, mas acho que é demais. De todo modo, provavelmente não é um requisito do AP.

Answer (score 4):

Fazer um `if` para verificar se o valor e igual a `''` já ajuda para o seu caso.

Ficaria assim no meu exemplo abaixo:

```js
let vagas = ['Fiat, Placa ABC-0123' , 'Tie Fighter, Placa kill-rebels', '', 'HB20, Placa ACB-0213' , 'Palio, Placa BCA-3210' , 'Kadett, CBA-2031', '', '']

console.log(`No estacionamento tem ${vagas.length} vagas`)
for (let lugar = 0; lugar < vagas.length; lugar++){
    if (vagas[lugar] === '')
     console.log(`A vaga ${lugar + 1} está vazia`)
    else
     console.log(`Na vaga ${lugar + 1} está o Automóvel ${vagas[lugar]}`)
   
}
```

Onde quando `vagas[lugar] === ''` for verdadeiro, vamos mostrar uma mensagem diferente no console, indicando que o lugar está vazio.