# Como verificar se existe uma propriedade em um objeto?

Tags: javascript

Estou puxando um usuário do back-end no meu front-end. Como faço para verificar se uma propriedade existe no objeto `usuario`?

Ex:

```
let usuario = {
  id: "1",
  name: "Jose",
  options: {
    channel: "1",
    reference: "a"
  },
  finished: "20/01/2021"
}
```

No caso só alguns usuários teriam a propriedade `finished`, mas como eu faria para verificar se um `usuario` tem essa propriedade?

Pensei em `user.finished === true`, mas obviamente não funcionou.
Também precisaria verificar caso o `usuario` não tivesse (por isso pensei no `true`, pois caso precisasse de um `usuario` sem essa propriedade eu colocaria `false`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao fazer `user.finished === true`, você está verificando se o valor da propriedade "finished" é `true`, não se ela existe.

Para fazer o que você quer, uma alternativa é usar [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty), passando o nome da propriedade:

```js
var user = {
    id: "1",
    name: "Jose",
    options: {
        channel: "1",
        reference: "a"
    },
    finished: "20/01/2021"
};

if (user.hasOwnProperty('finished')) {
    console.log('User tem propriedade finished');
} else {
    console.log('User não tem propriedade finished');
}
```

---

Provavelmente vão sugerir para apenas testar assim:

```
if (user.finished) {
    console.log('User tem propriedade finished');
}
```

O problema é que isso dará `false` caso a propriedade exista mas possua um [valor falseável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/112052):

```js
var user = {
    id: "1",
    name: "Jose",
    options: {
        channel: "1",
        reference: "a"
    },
    finished: ""
};

if (user.finished) {
    console.log('User tem propriedade finished');
} else {
    console.log('User não tem propriedade finished');
}
```

Repare no exemplo acima que a propriedade `finished` existe, mas como o valor dela é a string vazia (que é considerado "falso"), o código entra no `else`.

---

Podem ainda sugerir que você verifique se o valor é `undefined`, mas cai no mesmo problema: se ela existir e o valor for de fato `undefined`, também será considerado que não existe.

Veja a diferença:

```js
var user = {
    id: "1",
    name: "Jose",
    options: {
        channel: "1",
        reference: "a"
    },
    finished: undefined
};

if (user.finished) {
    console.log('User tem propriedade finished');
} else {
    console.log('User não tem propriedade finished');
}

if (user.finished !== undefined) {
    console.log('User tem propriedade finished');
} else {
    console.log('User não tem propriedade finished');
}

if (typeof user.finished !== "undefined") {
    console.log('User tem propriedade finished');
} else {
    console.log('User não tem propriedade finished');
}

if (user.hasOwnProperty('finished')) {
    console.log('User tem propriedade finished');
} else {
    console.log('User não tem propriedade finished');
}
```

No caso, o valor da propriedade é `undefined`. Os 3 primeiros testes consideram que a propriedade não existe (apesar dela existir, o problema é que `undefined` é um valor considerado `false`, e por isso o primeiro entra no `else`, e por ser `undefined`, os 2 seguintes também entram no `else` - só o último com `hasOwnProperty` de fato verifica se a propriedade existe, independente do valor).

Comment: Eu fiz isso e funcionou!!!! Porem eu não posso fazer uma verificação, tem alguma propriedade do tipo notownproperty ?

Comment: @Luckdev basta inverter a expressão boleana com `! user.hasOwnProperty('finished')`

Comment: @Luckdev Como já disseram: `if (! user.hasOwnProperty('finished')) { não tem a propriedade }` - qualquer condição booleana pode ser "invertida" com o uso do `!`

Comment: FUNCIONOU!!!!

Muito obrigado, tive que adaptar umas coisas pois oque eu estava fazendo estava bem diferente, porem era exatamente isso que eu precisava. (e eu viajei legal, pensei em utilizar o ! mas pensei na possibilidade de existir uma propriedade )
MUITO OBRIGADO!!!

Answer (score 3):

### Consideração sobre o título

O título da pergunta é *como verificar se existe uma propriedade no array?*, porém o tipo mostrado na pergunta não é um `Array`, e sim um `Object`.

## Solução 1

Talvez você possa verificar isso com `typeof`.

Veja:

```js
var user_1 = {
 id: "1",
 name: "Jose",
 options: {
  channel: "1",
  reference: "a"
 },
 finished: "20/01/2021"
}

var user_2 = {
 id: "1",
 name: "Jose",
 options: {
  channel: "1",
  reference: "a"
 }
}


console.log(typeof user_1.finished === 'undefined' ? 'Não possui' : 'Possui')
console.log(typeof user_2.finished === 'undefined' ? 'Não possui' : 'Possui')
```

`typeof` vai retornar o tipo da variável. Para valores não definidos, `typeof` retorna uma string com o valor 'undefined'`.

## Solução 2

Além disso, você pode usar o método `hasOwnProperty`. Esse método está disponíveis nos `Object` em Javascript.

Exemplo:

```js
var user_2 = {
   id: "1",
   name: "Jose",
   options: {
    channel: "1",
    reference: "a"
   }
}

console.log('Tem nome? %s', user_2.hasOwnProperty('name'))
console.log('Tem finished? %s', user_2.hasOwnProperty('finished'))
```

`HasOwnProperty` vai verificar se a propriedade foi definida ou não. No caso, se o valor for `false`, também vai retornar `true` para `hasOwnPropery`, já que ela verificar se a propriedade é definida, e não se o valor é vazio ou algo do tipo.

### Solução 3

Você pode também converter o valor de `finished` para `Boolean`. Nesse caso, ao invés de checar se a propriedade existe, vai converter o valor para `true` ou `false`, dependendo do conteúdo presente.

```js
console.log(!!user.finished);
```

No exemplo acima, se `user.finished` não for definido, tiver valor como `0`, `null` ou `''`, vai retornar `false` também. Caso tenha algo preenchido, com no exemplo da data colocado na sua pergunta, vai retornar `true`.

Então bastaria:

```js
if (!! user.finished) {
    // Valor existe
}
```

> **Nota**: Ao chamar uma propriedade inexistente de um objeto em Javascript, o mesmo costuma retornar `undefined`. Se você tiver a variável `var user = {id: 1}` e chamar `console.log(user.name)`, será retornado `undefined`.

Comment: Consideração sobre a consideração: arrays também são objetos e `hasOwnProperty` funciona com eles da mesma forma -> https://ideone.com/gUT8N5 :-)