# Problema em atribui valor a uma variável através de um else if

Tags: javascript

Ao fazer comparações com um valor numérico, ele sempre entra no primeiro `if`. Por que?

```
function calc() {
    let nome = document.querySelector("input#nome1").value
    let peso = document.querySelector("input#peso1").value
    let altura = document.querySelector("input#altura1").value
    let res = document.querySelector('div#res')
    
    let imc = Number(peso)/Number(altura)**2
    var media = '' 
    if (imc < 18,5) {
        media = 'Abaixo do peso'
    } else if (imc >= 18,50 && imc < 24,90) {
        media = 'com Peso normal'
    } else if (imc >= 24,90 && imc < 29,90) {
        media = 'com Sobrepeso'
    } else if (imc >= 29,90 && imc < 34,90) {
        media = 'com Obesidade grau I'
    } else if (imc >= 34,90 && imc < 39,90) {
        media = 'com Obesidade grau II'
    } else if (imc >= 40) {
        media = 'com Obesidade Morbida'
    }
    res.innerHTML = `Olá, ${nome}! seu IMC é ${imc.toFixed(2)} e está ${media}.`
        
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: O problema – ou pelo menos UM problema – é a vírgula nos seus valores numéricos. Você precisa usar ponto como separador das casas decimais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema, [como já dito nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/547177/problema-em-atribui-valor-a-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-atrav%c3%a9s-de-um-else-if#comment977920_547177), é ter usado a vírgula como separador decimal, quando o correto é usar o ponto. Ou seja, em vez de `18,5` deve ser `18.5`, o mesmo vale para todos os outros números.

Agora explicando o problema: a vírgula aí está funcionando como um [operador](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). Basicamente, uma expressão como `(a,b,c)` avalia todos os seus operandos (no caso, `a`, `b` e `c`) da esquerda para a direita e retorna o valor do último (no caso, `c`).

Isso quer dizer que o valor da expressão `(imc < 18,5)` é `5`. Não acredita? Pode conferir:

```js
let imc = 1000;
let x = (imc < 18,5);
console.log(x); // 5
```

Como a vírgula aí é um operador (e não o separador de casas decimais), você poderia inclusive escrever com espaços: `(imc < 18, 5)` ou `(imc < 18   ,   5)` funcionariam da mesma forma. No caso, em `(imc < 18,5)` temos duas expressões: a comparação `imc < 18` e a expressão `5`, ambos separados pelo operador vírgula.

E o resultado desta expressão é o valor do último operando, que no caso é `5`.

Depois, o `if` avalia o resultado desta expressão (que é `5`), e como o valor `5` [é considerado "verdadeiro"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/112052), ele sempre entra nesse `if`, independente do valor do `imc`. Veja:

```js
let imc = 1000;
if (imc < 18,5)
    console.log('ok'); // imprime "ok"
```

Embora a comparação `imc < 18` seja falsa, o resultado de toda a expressão é `5`, que é considerado verdadeiro. Por isso sempre entra no `if`.

Trocando para `18.5` funciona porque agora estamos usando o caractere correto para separar as casas decimais (ponto em vez de vírgula) e agora sim estaremos comparando o `imc` com "dezoito e meio".

Outro detalhe é que não precisa repetir os valores mais de uma vez, poderia ser apenas:

```js
let media = '';
if (imc < 18.5) {
    media = 'Abaixo do peso';
} else if (imc < 24.9) {
    media = 'com Peso normal';
} else if (imc < 29.9) {
    media = 'com Sobrepeso';
} else if (imc < 34.9) {
    media = 'com Obesidade grau I';
} else if (imc < 39.9) {
    media = 'com Obesidade grau II';
} else {
    media = 'com Obesidade Morbida';
}
```

Se não entrar no primeiro `if` é porque o `imc` com certeza é maior que `18.5`, então não precisa testar de novo no `else if` seguinte. E se não entrar no segundo `if`, é porque com certeza não é menor que `24.9` então não precisa testar isso no `else if` seguinte. E assim por diante. Por fim, no último `else` nem precisa testar nada, pois se chegou ali é porque não entrou em nenhuma das condições anteriores, então neste ponto eu sei que não é menor que `39.9`.

Repare também que `24.90` e `24.9` dá na mesma, então retirei esses zeros do final.

Claro que faltou validar se algum valor digitado é negativo, etc, mas aí você pode adicionar facilmente.

Answer (score 0):

Além do ponto levando por @bfavaretto, tem um pequeno problema de lógica dentro do seu `if`, por exemplo se o resultado for 39.99, não retornará sempre vazio na variável `media`.

Para identificar esse tipo de problema reforço fortemente a utilização de [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%C3%A9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%C3%A1-lo) para ver o resultado de seu bloco de algoritmo.

Você pode utilizar também a lógica inversa desse bloco, fazendo a comparação do número maior ao menor, comparando somente se for `>=`.

Por exemplo:

```js
let nome = "Fulano";
let peso = 80;
let altura = 1.85;

let imc = Number(peso)/Number(altura)**2;
var media = '';

if (imc >= 40.0){
  media = 'com Obesidade Morbida';
} else if (imc >= 34.9) {
  media = 'com Obesidade grau II';
} else if (imc >= 29.9) {
  media = 'com Obesidade grau I';
} else if (imc >= 24.9) {
  media = 'com Sobrepeso';
} else if (imc >= 18.5) {
  media = 'com Peso normal';
} else {
  media = 'Abaixo do peso';
}
    
console.log(`Olá, ${nome}! seu IMC é ${imc.toFixed(2)} e está ${media}.`);
```