# Estou fazendo um código sobre imc em html e js mas ele não roda

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Para um trabalho da faculdade meu professor pediu para criarmos um código que pedisse pelo nome, altura e peso, convertesse a altura e peso de int para float, fizesse o calculo do imc e retornasse o valor assim como a categoria na qual o usuário se enquadraria. meu código não roda, quando coloco os valores no input ele apenas recarrega a página. preciso de uma ajuda para descobrir o que fiz de errado, obrigada.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <html lang="pt-br">
        <title> Indice de massa corporal </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="form1">
            <label> Nome </label>
            <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="nome"> 
            <label> Qual sua altura? </label>
            <input type="int" id="altura" placeholder="altura">
            <label> Qual seu peso? </label>
            <input type="int" id="peso" placeholder="peso">
            <input type="submit" value="enviar" onclick="IMC">
        </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function IMC() {
                var altura = document.getElementById("altura").value;
                var peso = document.getElementById("peso").value;
                var m = peso / altura * altura;
                parseFloat(altura);
                parseFloat(peso);
        
                    if (m < 16){
                        var i = 'Baixo peso muito grave';
                    } else if (m > 16 && m < 16.99) {
                        var i = 'Baixo peso grave';
                    } else if (m > 17 && m < 18.49) {
                        var i = 'Baixo peso';
                    } else if (m > 18.50 && m < 24.99) {
                        var i = 'Peso normal';
                    } else if (m > 24 && m < 29.99) {
                        var i = 'Sobrepeso';
                    } else if (m > 30 && m < 34.99) {
                        var i = 'Obesidade de primeiro grau';
                    } else if (m > 35 && m < 39.99) {
                        var i = 'Obesidade de segundo grau'; 
                    } else if (m > 40) {
                        var i = 'Obesidade de terceiro grau';
                    }
                    document.write(nome + " possui indice de massa corporal igual a " + m + "sendo classificado como" + i);
                    }
            </script>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/547177/problema-em-atribui-valor-a-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-atrav%c3%a9s-de-um-else-if/547283#547283](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/547177/problema-em-atribui-valor-a-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-atrav%c3%a9s-de-um-else-if/547283#547283)

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

o document.write ele vai fazer com que, tudo que estava na tela sumar no lugar de document.write usa o innerHTML ou o innerTEXT

o <input type="submit" tira o submit, o submit vai fazer a pagina carregar quando vc enviar, troca por button.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Você chegou bem perto. Seu erro está na linha 18:

```
<input type="submit" value="enviar" onclick="IMC">
```

IMC é uma função, e funções devem ser chamadas como IMC(). Portanto, o correto para esse linha seria:

```
<input type="submit" value="enviar" onclick="IMC();"
```

Isso sozinho já vai fazer seu código funcionar, mas você mais alguns probleminhas.

Você vai perceber que o resultado vai mostrar 'undefined' no começo da linha. Isso é porquê na linha você chama a variável *nome*, mas você nunca a definiu.

```
document.write(nome + " possui indice de massa corporal igual a " + m + "sendo classificado como" + i);
```

Note que em nenhuma parte de seu código a variável *nome* foi definida.

No começo da sua função, onde você define as variáveis *altura*, *peso* e *m*, adicione a seguinte linha para definir a variável nome:

```
var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
```

Você vai notar também a falta de espaçamento em algumas strings.

**PRO TIP:**
Quando usar document.write(), adicione os tags HTML para formatar corretamente o sua saída, como por exemplo:

```
document.write("<h4>" + nome + " possui indice de massa corporal igual a " + m + "sendo classificado como" + i + "</h4>");
```

Ou ainda melhor, crie toda estrutura HTML que você precisa, deixando o valor em branco, e use javascript para simplesmente atualizar o valor do elemento.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Oi, obrigada, você ajudou bastante mas agora estou enfrentando outro erro. Os valores i e m retornam NaN e undefined

Comment: Verifique os campos e o tipo... esse NaN Not-A-Number (não é um número)..... indica que o valor não é um número

Comment: Oi Isa, conform o @stack.cardoso mencionou, NaN significa "Not A Number".  a variável i é definida como uma string, então isso é esperado. A variável m você pode evitar o erro usando parseInt(). Altere a linha da altura:
` var altura = document.getElementById("altura").value;` para:
` var altura = parseInt(document.getElementById("altura").value);`

Faça o mesmo com a linha do peso da mesma forma:
`var peso = parseInt(document.getElementById("peso").value);`

Isso vai resolver o problema de m retornando NaN.

Comment: Com relação à variável i, ela é sempre uma string e seu código não fez nenhum cálculo come la, portanto não vejo o que retornaria NaN nesse caso. Você lembrou de atualizar o seu código na pergunta original?

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <html lang="pt-br">
        <title> Indice de massa corporal </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="form1">
            <label> Nome </label>
            <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="nome"> 
            <label> Qual sua altura? </label>
            <input type="int" id="altura" placeholder="altura">
            <label> Qual seu peso? </label>
            <input type="int" id="peso" placeholder="peso">
            <input type="submit" value="enviar" onclick="IMC">
         </div>
        </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function imc() {
                var altura = document.getElementById("altura").value;
                var peso = document.getElementById("peso").value;
                var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;    
                var m = peso / altura * altura;
              
        
                    if (m < 16){
                        var i = 'Baixo peso muito grave';
                    } else if (m > 16 && m < 16.99) {
                        var i = 'Baixo peso grave';
                    } else if (m > 17 && m < 18.49) {
                        var i = 'Baixo peso';
                    } else if (m > 18.50 && m < 24.99) {
                        var i = 'Peso normal';
                    } else if (m > 24 && m < 29.99) {
                        var i = 'Sobrepeso';
                    } else if (m > 30 && m < 34.99) {
                        var i = 'Obesidade de primeiro grau';
                    } else if (m > 35 && m < 39.99) {
                        var i = 'Obesidade de segundo grau'; 
                    } else if (m > 40) {
                        var i = 'Obesidade de terceiro grau';
                    }
                    document.write(nome + " possui indice de massa corporal igual a " + m + "sendo classificado como" + i);
                    }
            </script>
       <input type="button" onClick="imc()" value="calcular">  
</body>
</html>
```

vc n declarou o nome como variavel, n chamou a funçao esse codigo ta funcionando aki espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).