# Por que "a < 0 || b < 0" não dá o mesmo resultado que "a || b < 0"?

Tags: javascript

Estava fazendo um teste e vi que esses dois códigos não davam o mesmo resultado. Por quê?

```js
function tudoPositivo(num1, num2, num3) {
  // Escreva aqui seu código
  if (num1 < 0 || num2 < 0 || num3 < 0) {
      return 'Tem negativo!'
  } else {
      return 'Tudo positivo!'
  }
}
```

```js
function tudoPositivo(num1, num2, num3) {
  // Escreva aqui seu código
  if (num1 || num2 || num3 < 0){
    return "Tem negativo!"
  } else {
    return "Tudo positivo!"
  }
}
```

Comment: isso depende dos valores que está passando para as funçoes. No segundo exemplo, é uma expressão onde, tecnicamete, "num1" deveria ser um boolean (true/false), mas se passar um número, vai entender zero como false e qualquer outro número como true

Comment: Olá João. É simplesmente confusão, o que leva a erro de uso, o que está entre os operadores || não são diretamente entendido pelos próximos, ou seja, funciona como `if (<primeira: testa primeira condição, se não vai para a segunda> || <segunda: testa segunda condição, se não vai para a terceira> || <terceira: testa a terceira, se não vai para o else, se existir>) {}`, em resumo, o operador de comparação `<` esta dentro da "terceira" condição.

Comment: Recomendo começar pelo básico do JavaScript aprendendo com o site mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics e indo diretamente ao ponto dos operadores https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators

Answer (score 3):

Em ambos os casos você está usando o operador `||` com três operandos. Se algum desses operandos for avaliado como "verdadeiro", a expressão como um todo também o será*****, e o código entrará no `if`.

Mas os códigos não são equivalentes porque os operandos não são os mesmos.

---

No primeiro código os operandos são:

- `num1 < 0`
- `num2 < 0`
- `num3 < 0`

Ou seja, para entrar no `if`, basta que algum dos valores seja um número negativo.

Já no segundo código, os operandos são:

- `num1`
- `num2`
- `num3 < 0`

Repare que agora não estamos mais vendo se `num1` ou `num2` são menores que zero. O que está sendo avaliado é **o próprio valor** dessas variáveis.

E aí caímos nas [regras de *truthy e falsy*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/112052): neste caso, somente os valores `null`, `undefined`, `±0`, `NaN` e strings vazias são considerados falsos. Qualquer outro valor é considerado verdadeiro.

Por exemplo, se `num1` ou `num2` for um número positivo, a condição será verdadeira e entrará no `if`.

---

***** Na verdade a expressão `a || b` retorna o valor de `a` (caso este seja um valor *truthy*) ou de `b` (caso `a` seja um valor *falsy*).