# Por que o operador "?:" é chamado de Elvis Operator?

Tags: terminologia, operadores

No PHP, costumo utilizar algumas expressões para simplificar a declaração de uma variável condicionalmente, através do operador `?:`.

Exemplo:

```php
function testing($usuario = null) {
    $usuario ?: $usuario = request()->user();
}
```

Vi que o operador `?:`  chama-se *Elvis Operator*, através [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/226652/4995).

Mas por qual motivo esse operador tem esse nome?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44133/101

Comment: Pra mim parece uma pessoa, 2 olhos e a mão na boca ou queixo `?:` https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2x2q.jpg --- poderia se chamar `weighting operator`

Comment: Se eu não me engano Elvis Operator é quando é usando como "Operador binário", já quando é usado como ternário é chamado de "Operador Ternário", portanto acho que depende da linguagem se ele será chamado de **Elvis Operator** ou **Ternary Operator**. Em PHP é chamado https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O Elvis é sempre um operador binário, e grafado exatamente `?:`. O  Operador Condicional (ternário é uma característica dele, e não o nome), não é o operador  `?:` e sim uma construção `Exp ? seV : seF `. "Quase por acaso" ambos usam os mesmos caracteres, mas cada um com um significado distinto. No caso do Operador Condicional , `?` é o operador e o `:` um delimitador). Deve ter sido proposital a semelhança para associar a um comportamento parecido, mas ainda assim são funcionalidades distintas.

Comment: Que tipo de fonte confiável você espera? Esse apelido é parte da cultura popular, por isso a wikipedia (artigo citado na resposta atual) seria uma das melhores fontes. Acho difícil que existam estudos acadêmicos sobre isso na área de ciência da computação ou etimologia.

Comment: @bfavaretto então podemos deixar a recompensa para bonificar a resposta existente. Minha ideia era colocar mais algumas dúvidas, mas preferi não fazê-lo para não prejudicar a resposta já dada.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Só meus 2 cents, se quiser bonificar uma futura resposta com uma recompensa, fique à vontade. A minha não sei se merece porque foi dada às pressas e não tenho prática para responder outras dúvidas, mas nada contra alguém responder inclusive aproveitando informações da minha resposta. Dá pra transformar ela em wiki também, não sei se perco os pontos (se perder também paciência, dá só uma dozinha porque veio bastante e sem muito esforço... como dizem, vem fácil, vai fácil :D). Tem só que ver se convém deixar todas as dúvidas numa pergunta só ou separar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O operador `?:` tem esse nome porque lembra o topete do cantor [Elvis Presley](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_Presley).

Veja:

[image: Exemplificando o Elvis Operator na prática]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator

Comment: Ótimo nome por sinal kkkkkkkkkk